# Finding the Dimension of OBJ objects

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, 3d, gameobject, obj

I am having a Three `OBJ` file , `Cone , Sphere and Cube`. How can i find the dimension of these objects , so that i can use it in my collision detection class.

i.e How can i find `Radius , Length of Cube and Radius and Height of cone`.
Or is there any better way for collision detection , I have Hundreds of random particle in my game which may or maynot collide with these objects.

Comment: What engine do you use?